# Linux using date Command to subset files then count the files

Tags: linux, date

I am using linux verison CentOS Linux 7 (Core).

I have files that look like this:
NameofArea_year_dayofyear_input

For example:
SanAntonio_2021_186_input

I would like to count how many files there are on yesterdays date.
For example this works and counts my files

```
find . -name "*_2021_186_input*" | wc -l
```

I am trying to make -name flag in `find` use the `date` command

This date command

```
date -d '-1 day' +'*_%Y_%j_input*'
```

Would produce
`*_2021_186_input*`
Which I would like to go into the `find`

I would expect this to work but it does not.

```
Day=`date -d '-1 day' +'*_%Y_%j_input*'`

find . -name $Day | wc -l
```

In fact it seems when I examine echo $Day is a list of my file names which does not make sense to me. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

EDIT:
Also I discovered when I do echo $Day in . where my files are located then it is a list of my file names.
When I do echo $Day in a different directory then it is the output I expect. "*_year_dayofyear_input*"

Comment: `find . -type f -name "*${Day}*" | wc -l`

Comment: @LMC That worked but why? Do the brackets turn it into plain text?

Comment: The brackets protect the var value from some shell expansions and stuff, you can read about that when you have time. What worked are the asterisks around that to make it a globbing pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting *and filename expansion*.

```
$ a='*'
$ set -x
$ echo *
+ echo file1.txt file2.txt ....
file1.txt file2.txt ....
```

When you put `*something*`  in a variable and then unquoted `$Day` undergoes filename expansion, which expands it to list of paths *before running the command*.

```
$ Day='*_2021_186_input*'
$ find . -name $Day | wc -l
+ find . -name file1_2021_186_input file2_2021_186_input ...
```

You want to pass `*` *literally* to `find`. I see no reason to put `*` in day, just:

```
day=$(date -d '-1 day' +'_%Y_%j_input')
find . -name "*$day*" | wc -l
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.net

Comment: Yes this is the case. Thank you!